# Not getting all videos of iPhone using PHCachingImageManager

Tags: ios, swift, video, fetch, photo-gallery

I am using `PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAssetForVideo` to fetch videos from iPhone. I am not getting all the videos from my iPhone. Videos stored in Photos are being fetched not all.

How can I get all the videos stored in iPhone storage.

Here is the code.

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()

options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
            ascending: true)]

        let assetResults = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video,
                                                            options: options)        

        for i in 0 ..< assetResults.count{

            let object: AnyObject = assetResults[i]

            if let asset = object as? PHAsset{

                let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
                options.deliveryMode = .Automatic
                options.networkAccessAllowed = true
                options.version = .Current
                options.progressHandler = {(progress: Double,
                    error: NSError?,
                    stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>,
                    info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in

            }

                /* Now get the video */
                PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(asset,options: options,resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?,audioMix: AVAudioMix?,info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    /* Did we get the URL to the video? */
                    if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset{


                })

                })

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look inside `PHFetchOptions` Maybe some of your video assets are hidden?

```
var fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.includeHiddenAssets = true
```

From the Docs-

> // Whether hidden assets are included in fetch results. Defaults to NO
>
> public var includeHiddenAssets: Bool

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried it, but not working.

Comment: Anything common with the videos not being fetched?

Comment: They are not in the "Camera Roll" folder.

Comment: They are in other Albums. Manually created Album.

Comment: How are they absent from "Camera Roll" ? All the videos are still inside "Camera Roll" even if you create personal albums.

Comment: But they are being fetched by other video apps I downloaded from app store.